# Is the intensity of light dependent on number of photons per unit area?

Tags: visible-light, photoelectric-effect, intensity

I was learning about the photoelectric effect of light and there it says more the intensity of light, the more number of electrons will be ejected from the metal surface given that the frequency of light is more than its threshold frequency.

Now what does intensity basically means?? Is it dependent on the number of photons per unit area over which the light falls..

Let us consider two light rays, $X$ and $Y$ which have same frequency and same wavelength and it is said that $X$ has more intensity than $Y$. The light rays fall over an area, $dA$. Does that mean that light ray $X$ will have more photons falling on that area $dA$ as compared to light ray $Y$ ??

Comment: Relevant discussion about what *intensity* means for classical and quantum EM waves: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/669786/247642

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes

> light ray X will have more photons falling on that area dA as compared to light ray Y

(per second).

The energy of each photon depends on its frequency from $E=hf$.
If $X$ and $Y$ have the same frequency, then more photons per second are falling on the area, from light $X$.

This matches with the classical definition of Intensity (power per unit area)

Answer (score 1):

Number of photons per unit area is proportional to intensity. That’s because intensity = power/area = (energy/time)/area. A photon has energy $h\nu$, where $\nu$ is the frequency. So intensity is $N h\nu$/(time x area), where $N$ is the number of photons.